# Using a Macro to delete a procedure in an Excel VBA Module

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Workbook that has multiple modules. One module has multiple macros (well over 100). I am looking for a way to enter the macro name in a cell, then have a button that will find that macro in the module and delete it. I don't want to delete then entire module because it has several macros that are still needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next `Sub`, please. It requires a refference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications extensibility 5.3'. It deletes a procedure from a module of active document. The code can be easily adapted to delete from any open workbook:

```
Private Sub DeleteProc(moduleName As String, procName As String)
'It needss a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications extensibility 5.3'
Dim VBCodeM As CodeModule, firstLine As Long, procLines As Long, WB As Workbook

Set WB = ActiveWorkbook 'you can use a different workbook

On Error Resume Next
 Set VBCodeM = WB.VBProject.VBComponents(moduleName).CodeModule
 If Err.Number = 9 Then
    Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "No module named """ & moduleName & """ in workbook """ & WB.Name & """."
    Exit Sub
 End If
On Error GoTo 0

    'starting line for the procedure
    On Error Resume Next
     firstLine = VBCodeM.ProcStartLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
     If Err.Number = 35 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        MsgBox "No procedure named """ & procName & """ in module """ & moduleName & """."
        Exit Sub
     End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If firstLine > 0 Then

        'number of lines in the procedure
        procLines = VBCodeM.ProcCountLines(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
         'Delete all the lines
         VBCodeM.DeleteLines firstLine, procLines
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I can't tell you how long I've been working on this.  I did have to take the "ByVal moduleName As String, ByVal procName As String" out of the procedure line because I couldn't get the macro to run, so I just added "Dim ModuleName As String, ProcName As String".

Comment: @Cyndi: Glad I could help you! `ByVal` could be avoided. It is standard VBA if nothing specified. Only `ByRef` is required in case you need to also modify the source inside the Function/Sub, using it like parameter. Anyhow, it worked on my installation as it is, but I will delete `ByVal`. It is not of any use in this circumstance. Adapted the code...